# Storm UI with streamparse

Tags: nimbus, apache-storm, apache-zookeeper, streamparse

I am working on an `streamparse` project on an AWS instance with ZooKeeper and Nimbus installed. I want to use the Storm UI. I ran `sparse submit` with the following config.json file:

```
{
    "library": "",
    "topology_specs": "topologies/",
    "virtualenv_specs": "virtualenvs/" ,
    "envs": {
        "prod": {
            "user": "ubuntu",
            "nimbus": "127.0.0.1",
            "workers": [
                "127.0.0.1"
            ],
            "log": {
                "path": "/var/log/storm/streamparse",
                "max_bytes": 100000,
                "backup_count": 10,
                "level": "info"
            },
            "use_ssh_for_nimbus": false,
            "use_virtualenv": false,
            "virtualenv_root": ".virtualenvs/storm"
        }
    }
}
```

It gives following error trace:

```
Cleaning from prior builds...
Creating topology Uber-JAR...
Uber-JAR created: /home/ubuntu/airstorm/_build/wordcount-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-standalone.jar
Deploying "wordcount" topology...
Routing Python logging to /var/log/storm/streamparse.
Running lein command to submit topology to nimbus:
lein run -m streamparse.commands.submit_topology/-main topologies/wordcount.clj --host 127.0.0.1 --port 6627 --option 'topology.workers=2' --option 'topology.acker.executors=2' --option 'streamparse.log.path="/var/log/storm/streamparse"' --option 'streamparse.log.max_bytes=100000' --option 'streamparse.log.backup_count=10' --option 'streamparse.log.level="info"'
{:option {streamparse.log.level info, streamparse.log.backup_count 10, streamparse.log.max_bytes 100000, streamparse.log.path /var/log/storm/streamparse, topology.acker.executors 2, topology.workers 2}, :debug false, :port 6627, :host 127.0.0.1, :help false}
Caught exception: org.apache.thrift7.transport.TTransportException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused

java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.thrift7.transport.TTransportException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
 at backtype.storm.utils.NimbusClient.getConfiguredClient (NimbusClient.java:38)
    backtype.storm.StormSubmitter.submitTopology (StormSubmitter.java:116)
    backtype.storm.StormSubmitter.submitTopology (StormSubmitter.java:70)
    streamparse.commands.submit_topology$submit_topology_BANG_.invoke (submit_topology.clj:23)
    streamparse.commands.submit_topology$_main.doInvoke (submit_topology.clj:86)
    clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke (RestFn.java:2422)
    clojure.lang.Var.invoke (Var.java:496)
    user$eval5.invoke (form-init6482794978849376851.clj:1)
    clojure.lang.Compiler.eval (Compiler.java:6619)
    clojure.lang.Compiler.eval (Compiler.java:6609)
    clojure.lang.Compiler.load (Compiler.java:7064)
    clojure.lang.Compiler.loadFile (Compiler.java:7020)
    clojure.main$load_script.invoke (main.clj:294)
    clojure.main$init_opt.invoke (main.clj:299)
    clojure.main$initialize.invoke (main.clj:327)
    clojure.main$null_opt.invoke (main.clj:362)
    clojure.main$main.doInvoke (main.clj:440)
    clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke (RestFn.java:421)
    clojure.lang.Var.invoke (Var.java:419)
    clojure.lang.AFn.applyToHelper (AFn.java:163)
    clojure.lang.Var.applyTo (Var.java:532)
    clojure.main.main (main.java:37)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at streamparse.commands.submit_topology$submit_topology_BANG_.invoke(submit_topology.clj:28)
    at streamparse.commands.submit_topology$_main.doInvoke(submit_topology.clj:86)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:2422)
    at clojure.lang.Var.invoke(Var.java:496)
    at user$eval5.invoke(form-init6482794978849376851.clj:1)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:6619)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:6609)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.load(Compiler.java:7064)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.loadFile(Compiler.java:7020)
    at clojure.main$load_script.invoke(main.clj:294)
    at clojure.main$init_opt.invoke(main.clj:299)
    at clojure.main$initialize.invoke(main.clj:327)
    at clojure.main$null_opt.invoke(main.clj:362)
    at clojure.main$main.doInvoke(main.clj:440)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:421)
    at clojure.lang.Var.invoke(Var.java:419)
    at clojure.lang.AFn.applyToHelper(AFn.java:163)
    at clojure.lang.Var.applyTo(Var.java:532)
    at clojure.main.main(main.java:37)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/storm/bin/sparse", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/storm/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/streamparse/cli/sparse.py", line 53, in main
    args.func(args)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/storm/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/streamparse/cli/submit.py", line 242, in main
    wait=args.wait, simple_jar=args.simple_jar)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/storm/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/streamparse/cli/submit.py", line 204, in submit_topology
    host=host, port=port)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/storm/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/streamparse/cli/submit.py", line 136, in _submit_topology
    run(full_cmd)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/storm/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/invoke/runner.py", line 349, in run
    return runner.run(command, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/storm/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/invoke/runner.py", line 153, in run
    raise Failure(result)
invoke.exceptions.Failure: Command execution failure!

Exit code: 1

Stderr:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at streamparse.commands.submit_topology$submit_topology_BANG_.invoke(submit_topology.clj:28)
    at streamparse.commands.submit_topology$_main.doInvoke(submit_topology.clj:86)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:2422)
    at clojure.lang.Var.invoke(Var.java:496)
    at user$eval5.invoke(form-init6482794978849376851.clj:1)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:6619)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:6609)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.load(Compiler.java:7064)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.loadFile(Compiler.java:7020)
    at clojure.main$load_script.invoke(main.clj:294)
    at clojure.main$init_opt.invoke(main.clj:299)
    at clojure.main$initialize.invoke(main.clj:327)
    at clojure.main$null_opt.invoke(main.clj:362)
    at clojure.main$main.doInvoke(main.clj:440)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:421)
    at clojure.lang.Var.invoke(Var.java:419)
    at clojure.lang.AFn.applyToHelper(AFn.java:163)
    at clojure.lang.Var.applyTo(Var.java:532)
    at clojure.main.main(main.java:37)
```